# Calling C# sessions using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have created a session using .net and c#. I am trying to call that session on jquery using the code below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( '<%=Session["CoBrowse"].ToString() %>' );
});
```

However, the console treats it as a string and not a c# code. Hence the output is:

```
'<%=Session["CoBrowse"].ToString() %>'
```

and not the session code.

Comment: ASP is executed on the server, JavaScript on the client/browser. You cannot just mix that randomly.

Comment: I have done it before somehow and it has worked, I have also seen other pages on stackoverflow with people using the same code and it has worked.....

Comment: the file is an aspx file

Comment: Remove the quotes so that the command is executed on the server putting the value of the session variable in the HTML sent to the client.

Comment: Could you show me how, as I think I did what you said and it did not make any difference...

Comment: <%= is for ASPX pages.  Is this what your page is? If it's cshtml you would do '@Session["CoBrowse"].ToString()'

Comment: Do you have this code in your .aspx file or some external .js file? It needs to be in the .aspx file.

Comment: Is this in a <script> tag on the ASPX page?  It will not work if this is a JS file that is included.

Comment: Im using kentico, it is a seperate file

Comment: separate file won't work. it has to be in aspx file.

Comment: You said above _“the file is an aspx file”_. If it is not an aspx file, then it cannot work since the server won’t process the file.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs at Client Side and sessions are maintained at Server side. So these two things can not work side by side. However you can do something like this

```
    <script runat="Server">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( '<%=Session["CoBrowse"].ToString() %>' );
  });

 </script>
```

Comment: When I do that, the console prints out this: <%=Session["CoBrowse"].ToString() %>

Comment: @AmirAli did you add
 `<script runat="server">`

Comment: Yes I did, it still gives me the same output

Comment: @AmirAli and this script is added in .aspx file?

Comment: Yes brother in the ascx file